# Reading database with python

Tags: javascript, python

The database located at this address http://www.stiftelser.lst.se/StiftWeb/SSearch.aspx uses some javascript code to show more results. This is the code it uses:

javascript:__doPostBack('grdResult$_ctl14$_ctl1',")

Executing this javascript through clicking the link to show more results does not change the url of the page. Is it still possible for a python script to execute the javascript and get more results from the database?

What I really want for my python script is to see the entries in the database, each entry has an ID which you can append at the end of the URL: http://www.stiftelser.lst.se/StiftWeb/FoundationDetails.aspx?id=IDNUMBER_HERE.

The id seems to be ranging from 1000000 to about 1040000, but with only 13136 entries in total. You could create an index the bruteforce way by simply looking for entries that contain information, but I would like to find a way that's a bit more elegant if there is one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059822/submitting-queries-to-and-scraping-results-from-aspx-pages-using-python

Answer (score 0):

are you using any framework? the simple logic for this is this:

you submit the form with `GET` method, so that you can see the parameters in the url and play with that data in the serverside and render back. is it what you want?

i think, you know what html form is and what sending httpresponse means..

hope that helps a bit

btw: not changing the url is more the thing of ajax, may be you try it also