# Post forms using requests on .net website (python)

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests

headers ={
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Connection":"keep-alive",
"Host":"mcfbd.com",
"Referer":"https://mcfbd.com/mcf/FrmView_PropertyTaxStatus.aspx",
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"}

a = requests.session()
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.get("https://mcfbd.com/mcf/FrmView_PropertyTaxStatus.aspx").content)

payload = {"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearchHouse":"",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearchSector":"",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPropertyID":"",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtownername":"",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlZone":"1",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSector":"2",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlBlock":"2",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnFind":"Search",
"__VIEWSTATE":soup.find('input',{'id':'__VIEWSTATE'})["value"],
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":"14039419",
"__EVENTVALIDATION":soup.find("input",{"name":"__EVENTVALIDATION"})["value"],
"__SCROLLPOSITIONX":"0",
"__SCROLLPOSITIONY":"0"}

b = a.post("https://mcfbd.com/mcf/FrmView_PropertyTaxStatus.aspx",headers = headers,data = payload).text
print(b)
```

above is my code for this website.

```
https://mcfbd.com/mcf/FrmView_PropertyTaxStatus.aspx
```

I checked firebug out and these are the values of the form data.
however doing this:

```
b = requests.post("https://mcfbd.com/mcf/FrmView_PropertyTaxStatus.aspx",headers = headers,data = payload).text
print(b)
```

throws this error:

```
[ArgumentException]: Invalid postback or callback argument
```

is my understanding of submitting forms via request correct?

**1.open firebug**

**2.submit form**

**3.go to the NET tab**

**4.on the NET tab choose the post tab**

**5.copy form data like the code above**

I've always wanted to know how to do this. I could use selenium but I thought I'd try something new and use requests

Answer (score 2):

The error you are receiving is correct because the fields like _VIEWSTATE (and others as well) are not static or hardcoded. The proper way to do this is as follows:

Create a Requests Session object. Also, it is advisable to update it with headers containing USER-AGENT string -

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36",}`
s = requests.session()
```

Navigate to the specified url -

```
r = s.get(url)
```

Use [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the html returned -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
```

Populate formdata with the hardcoded values and dynamic values -

```
formdata = {
   '__VIEWSTATE': soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '__VIEWSTATE'})['value'],
   'field1': 'value1'
}
```

Then send the POST request using the session object itself -

```
s.post(url, data=formdata)
```

Comment: We are using Session object to maintain session (i.e. cookies)

Comment: does the order matter? I mean the order of the parameters? no right?

Comment: No the order doesnt matter at all.

Comment: one more thing I get this error `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` doing this `a = requests.sessions()`

Comment: It is `requests.session()` and not `sessions` ... notice an unwanted `s` at the end.

Comment: we're almost there. why do I get this error now? `[ArgumentException]: Invalid postback or callback argument` i'll update my question